# Problem trying to extract words from string in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, string-parsing

I'm trying to extract all words from a string into an array, but i am having some problems with spaces (`&nbsp;`).

This is what I do:

```
//Clean data to text only
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data = htmlspecialchars_decode($data);
$data = mb_strtolower($data, 'UTF-8');

//Clean up text from special chrs I don't want as words
$data = str_replace(',', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('.', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(':', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(';', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('*', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('?', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('!', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('-', ' ', $data);
$data = str_replace("\n", ' ', $data);
$data = str_replace("\r", ' ', $data);
$data = str_replace("\t", ' ', $data);
$data = str_replace("\0", ' ', $data);
$data = str_replace("\x0B", ' ', $data);
$data = str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $data);

//Clean up duplicated spaces
do {
   $data = str_replace('  ', ' ', $data);
} while(strpos($data, '  ') !== false);

//Make array
$clean_data = explode(' ', $data);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($clean_data);
echo "</pre>";
```

**This outputs:**

```
array(58) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) " "
  [1]=>
  string(5) " "
  [2]=>
  string(11) "anläggning"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "med"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "den"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "erfarenhet"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "som"
}
```

If i check source for output i see that the first 2 array values is `&nbsp;`.
No matter how I try, I can't remove this from the string. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
After some tweaking with code i manage to get following output:

```
array(56) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "�" //Notice change. Instead of string length 5 it now says 1. But still its garbage.
  [1]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "anläggning"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "med"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "den"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "erfarenhet"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "som"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "finns"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "inom"
```

Thanks!

**ANSWER (for lazy people):**

Even thou this is a slightly different approach to the problem, and it never really answers why I had the problems I had above (like leftover `&nbsp;` and other extra weird spaces), I like it and it is a lot better than my original code.

Thanks to all who contributed to this!

```
//Clean data to text only
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data = htmlspecialchars_decode($data);
$data = mb_strtolower($data, 'UTF-8');

//Clean up text from special chrs
$data = str_replace(array("-"), ' ', $data);    

$clean_data = str_word_count($data, 1, 'äöå');

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($clean_data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: you sure the actual data contains the &nbsp; (and not only the output generated by var_dump) ?

Comment: Someone is going to post a version of this that does the same thing correctly in about 6 lines :)

Comment: JohnSmith: Yes. I get same if I do echo $data[0] or echo $data[1].

Comment: thirtydot: I would be very happy if someone did so. :) But this is harder than one might expect, specialy since I am working with UTF-8 and characters such as ÅÄÖ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the only thing you would have to do is to replace `&nbsp;` with a space as you already do (only if the string really still contains `&nbsp;` check [@Andy E's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450254/problem-trying-to-extract-words-from-string-in-php/4450365#4450365) to make sure that that your data does not contain any HTML entities.):

```
$data = str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $data);
```

Then you can use [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to get the words:

```
$words = str_word_count($data, 1, 'äöåÄÖÅ');
```

P.S.: What is the sense of calling `htmlentities` first and then revert it again in with `html_entity_decode` anyway?

**Update:** Example:

```
$str = '      anläggning med den      erfahrenhet som åååÅ ÅÅ';
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1, 'äöåÄÖÅ'));
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => anläggning
    [1] => med
    [2] => den
    [3] => erfahrenhet
    [4] => som
    [5] => åååÅ
    [6] => ÅÅ
)
```

Reading documentation helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately str_word_count doesn't work with åäö. It cuts all words as two words when it hits å, ä or ö.

Comment: You can pass in a custom `$charlist` as the third argument to `str_word_count` - "A list of additional characters which will be considered as 'word'"

Comment: @jamietelin: As @thirthdot says, pass a string with extra characters that should considered part of the word. It is described in the documentation I linked to. Believe me, reading documentation helps!

Comment: @jamietelin: Depends, not every documentation is good and not every problem is addressed in documentation... but stackoverflow should not be a replacement for reading documentation. They should be consulted first imo.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks for pointing out how `str_word_count` works :) If we all read every documentation, stackoverflow wouldn't be needed i guess (it is a joke). I didn't even know when I started this that there was such a thing as `str_word_count`. Ty a lot!

Comment: @jamietelin: No worries, I didn't mean to sound harsh... happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're "double encoding" any existing `&nbsp;` parts of the string?  You call `htmlentities` on the string before `html_entity_decode`, so any existing `&nbsp;` characters would become `&amp;nbsp;`.  You can prevent `htmlentities` from double encoding by providing `false` as the fourth parameter.

```
$data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Also, bare in mind that you can pass an array for matches in `str_replace`:

```
$data = str_replace(array(',','.',':',';','*','?','!','-'), '', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
14x str_replace

do {
   $data = str_replace('  ', ' ', $data);
} while(strpos($data, '  ') !== false);
```

do:

```
$data = preg_replace('/[.*,:;?!]/', '', $data);
$data = preg_replace('/(?:\xC2\xA0|\s{2,}|-)/', ' ', $data);
```

Whereas `0xC2A0` is the non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) and `\s` is any white-space character covering the repeated `str_replace` calls.

Comment: This actually did something. But instead of a space, I get some weird character I cant post here it seems.

Comment: Is the "weird character" a `0xC2`?

Comment: goreSplatter: I want to kiss you right now! I tested "your character" `$data = str_replace(array("\xC2"), ' ', $data);` and it worked!!! What the hell is that character `0xC2`?!

Comment: See my edit. `0xC2A0` is the Unicode for the [Non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r( explode(" ", $data));
```

**Update**

```
define("WORD_COUNT_MASK", "/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}'\x{2019}]*/u");

function str_word_count_utf8($str)
{
     preg_match_all(WORD_COUNT_MASK, $str, $matches);
     print_r( $matches);
}
str_word_count_utf8( $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort?! But this didn't do anything. It is exactly what i already do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '&nbsp; cesadasdsadas <br /> &nbsp; dsadsadas';
$data = preg_replace('/&nbsp;/', ' ', $data);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference :/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

I've made something close to your goal recently :

```
    $words = array_unique(str_word_count($CONTENT." ".$TITLE, 1));
    sort($words);
    $words = addslashes (implode(" ", array_values($words)));
```

Bye.

Comment: Unfortunately str_word_count doesn't work with åäö. It cuts all words as two words when it hits å, ä or ö.